# Can I use smartphone barometer to measure underwater pressure?

Tags: android, algorithm, pressure

I am trying to do an algorithm to measure the underwater pressure and how depth I am. My Android device is water proof and has a barometer sensor.
   I am getting strange readings from barometer when device is underwater so I am not sure if that sensor works in underwater condition.

Does anyone know if the barometer for android devices (Galaxy S7 device, pressure sensor LPS25H from STMicroeletronics) works underwater? Shall I add a kind of correction parameter in the algorithm to get proper preassure measures when underwater?

thanks!

Comment: Sounds more like an electronics/physics question. Of course the sensor's intended operating range might easily be exceeded underwater if it's designed for a realistic atmospheric pressure range. And what effect does a possible air bubble stuck between the sensor and the water have(?)